# Is it possible to add text (e.g. a transcription or lyrics) to AMR or OPUS sound files?

Tags: audio, gmail, metadata, opus, amr

Is it possible to add text (e.g. a transcription or lyrics) to AMR or OPUS sound files? Googling for this mostly returns transcription services, not whether there are defined meta data fields for this purpose?

And secondly, if the answer is yes, does Google (Gmail or Gdrive) index this text (like they do with PDFs - if you search for a string in Gmail or Gdrive it returns mails where the string only appears in an attached PDF).

Answer (score 0):

This depends completely on the container format.

Neither the AMR codec nor the Opus codec specify any particular container format. Both of them can be encapsulated in a variety of different containers. Most container formats have some capability of encapsulating additional metadata. But this is a feature of the container format, not the audio stream.

Comment: Hmm, I have .amr and .opus files. Aren't the extension indicating the container format?

Comment: I just opened one file of each type in VLC and opened the file info window. Nothing there said anything but amr or opus. How can I check which container the files are using?